# Servlet.service() exception when using sendRedirect()

Tags: jsp, struts2

I received the following error after increasing response buffer:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.redirects.redirects_005flist_jsp._jspService(redirects_005flist_jsp.java:325)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:393)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:261)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:581)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm putting below line in the JSP:

```
Welcome <%=userSession.getFirstName() %>!
```

since the user session is null it should redirect to login page, but it is not and when it reaches the above line it is throwing exception.

Comment: edited the error now I'm getting

Comment: Can you post your code. That will help in solving your issues.

Comment: Thanks for all your help..its resolved now

Answer (score 0):

I think the response is committed before the `sendRedirect()` happened.

Response committing might happen due to the reasons [Causes for Response comitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305563/cause-of-servlets-response-already-committed/11305612#11305612)

Comment: I increased the buffer size if the jsp but still getting the same error

Comment: Increase the response buffer size also. Edited the link in my answer please check.

Comment: How to increase response buffer size?

Comment: ServletRespnse.setBufferSize(), the link in my answer explains this.

Comment: if (userSession == null){
  //response.sendRedirect("../login.jsp?currenturl=" + currentURL);
  response.setBufferSize(2000);
  response.sendRedirect("../login.jsp");
 }and i'm getting above error(as edited)..I have no idea why it is coming out of the if block.

Comment: sendRedirect() wont conclude the request/response. You need to return after that to prevent any code below that line from executing.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should replace every time you use

```
resposnse.redirect("abc.jsp");
```

with

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("abc.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
```

beginning from the first time you used it in the very project or session