# Cause of Servlet's 'Response Already Committed'

Tags: exception, servlets, response

What are the common possibilities to encounter this exception in servlet - Response Already committed?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The response gets committed because of the following reasons:

- Because the Response buffer has reached the max buffer size. It could be because of the following reasons:

  ```
    > the bufferSize in JSP page has reached.You can increase the JSP buffer size 
      in page directive. See here, 

     <%@ page buffer="5kb" autoFlush="false" %>

    > the server default response max buffer size has reached.You can increase    
      the server default max buffer size.

      ServletRespnse.setBufferSize()
  ```
- Some part of the code has called flushed on the response , i,e, invoked the method `HttpServletResponse.flushBuffer()`.
- Some part of the code has flushed the `OutputStream` or `Writer`, i,e, invoked the method `HttpServletResponse.getOutputStream().flush()` or `HttpServletResponse.getWriter().flush()
- If you have forwarded to another page, where the response is both committed and closed. For example, when response.sendRedirect() has been called, the response is committed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Deliberately we never call any of these. But, flush="true" would cause this? So, what are the measures to consider to avoid this?

Comment: Increase the buffer size of the jsp.

Comment: How to do this? Can you explain with some example?

Comment: You are having JSP or servlet?

Comment: I actually would like to know the exact cause of this. This occurs both in servlet / jsp. You primarily focused on buffer size. Are there any other points to consider to avoid this. Anyways, your reply certainly helps me. Thanks.

Comment: This can happen in several cases. Have listed all the cases. Added one more case as well.

Comment: What you mean by this _the response is both committed and closed_ ?

Comment: Committed means just writing headers. Close means writing headers + writing response + close stream. Such that you cannot write any more content.

Comment: Check this thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34292303/why-i-can-still-send-data-after-the-response-is-commited-with-response-flushbuf). You can still write to client **even after** you call `HttpServletResponse.flushBuffer()`.

Comment: Yes, Sending data is different from committing !! Committing data is just writing headers. In my discussion above committing data means writing headers.