# java servlet printwriter API insert string at some position

Tags: html, servlets, jakarta-ee, printwriter

I am using PrintWriter in one my servlet to flush html like below

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println("<html>");
out.println("<head>");
out.println("</head>");
out.println("<body>");
out.println("</body>");
out.println("</html>");
```

Say now i want to insert one line in html body. Is there a way to insert the data at some specific line at later stage or we have to go sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to insert lines.

If you really want to produce HTML pages this way (via `PrintWriter` and `println()`), you can create a `String` that contains something like a Template:

```
String template = "<html><head></head> <body> <p>__PLACEHOLDER1__</p> <p>__PLACEHOLDER2__</p> ... </body></html>";
```

During execution you replace the placeholders whenever you want.

Another way: you clean the buffer [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15593188/1988304) and restart the output over all.

But I suggest to create the HTML via JSP, JSF or something like that