# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed while including HTML files using jsp:include

Tags: spring, jsp, servlets, jspinclude

When `<jsp:include>` is used for including HTML file `DispatcherServlet` is throwing

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed
```

I have one servlet:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>web</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In it, I have enabled Spring MVC annotations and have handler mapping and adapter for JSP files without controllers (converting old webapp to Spring). And I have enabled `DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler` in this Servlet.

Any idea how to avoid that `IllegalStateException` when including html files?

Comment: upload the rest of your code

Comment: Try with `<jsp:forward>` instead of `<jsp:include>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you let spring handle all html files, it will always fail on `jsp:include` because spring cannot handle html includes.

Best way around this for me was to leave html files on default servlet.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and leave rest on `DispatcherServlet`.

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>web</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>web</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This is definitely not a best solution, but until I convert all jsps (around 1000 of them) to mvc and something like tiles this is the only way I can see it working.

Answer (score 0):

It is illegal to call forward() after some response is written to the output stream. The response may have been already sent to the client.

This article [Causes of Response already committed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305563/cause-of-servlets-response-already-committed) explains why response is already committed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the proposed solution which declares the default servlet mapping for `*.html` url patterns and it worked fine. The only problem was that it introduced some side effects in my case (an hybrid webapp, spring and non-spring managed): html files that should have been managed by Spring's front controller now were managed by Tomcat's default controller.
Fortunately, I found a couple of solutions with zero impact on the rest of the webapp.

1. Use .jsp file extension instead of .html. Spring won't complain if
   it finds `<jsp:include page="file.jsp" />` instead of `<jsp:include page="file.html" />`
2. Include the .html file in a scriptlet `<%=file.html %>` and avoid using the jsp "include" tag