# return error code from jsp custom tag's doStartTag() or doEndTag()

Tags: java, servlets, jsp-tags, custom-tags

I want to send error code as response from jsp custom tag but it doesn't work.
Currently it looks like this:

```
try {
     response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
} catch (IOException e) {
    LOGGER.error("Couldn't send error response code.", e);
}
return SKIP_PAGE;
```

Comment: What are you getting? Any error message or unwanted output ?

Comment: One common situation is the response being already committed. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305563/cause-of-servlets-response-already-committed

Comment: @Anil Reddy I have cms that should intercept error code and show default page for that error code... but it doesn't load that page, it just returns to originally requested page.

Comment: Can you change your return statement to EVAL_PAGE. and try it once

Comment: @AnilReddy got same result as with SKIP_PAGE.