# Spring Boot response has already been committed exception for request to resources

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, wildfly

I'm using Spring Boot (v1.2.4) deployed on WildFly 8.2 server. On the application I'm using font awesome v4.3.

I get the "response already committed exception" as below stack trace for three files each of which are less than 100kb.

1. fontawesome-webfont.eot
2. fontawesome-webfont.woff
3. fontawesome-webfont.ttf

There are many other resources > 100kb in size and still get served successfully.

The stack trace is as below

```
    2015-06-15 15:52:29,547 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter] (default task-3) Cannot forward to error page for request [/resources/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:55) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:148) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:504) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
        at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.write(NioSocketConduit.java:161)
        at io.undertow.conduits.AbstractFramedStreamSinkConduit.doWrite(AbstractFramedStreamSinkConduit.java:140) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.conduits.AbstractFramedStreamSinkConduit.write(AbstractFramedStreamSinkConduit.java:108) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.protocol.ajp.AjpServerResponseConduit.write(AjpServerResponseConduit.java:270) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel.write(ConduitStreamSinkChannel.java:150)
        at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSinkChannel.write(DetachableStreamSinkChannel.java:239) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$WriteDispatchChannel.write(HttpServerExchange.java:1850) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.writeBufferBlocking(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:567) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.write(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:220) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper.java:457) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.copy(StreamUtils.java:124) [spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.writeContent(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:409) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:241) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:295) [spring-boot-actuator-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:1.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:51) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter.processLogout(SAMLLogoutFilter.java:164) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar:1.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter.doFilter(SAMLLogoutFilter.java:106) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar:1.0.1.RELEASE]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.processLogout(SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.java:206) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar:1.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.doFilter(SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.java:104) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar:1.0.1.RELEASE]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLDiscovery.doFilter(SAMLDiscovery.java:137) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar:1.0.1.RELEASE]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint.doFilter(SAMLEntryPoint.java:103) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar:1.0.1.RELEASE]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataDisplayFilter.doFilter(MetadataDisplayFilter.java:84) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar:1.0.1.RELEASE]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar:1.0.1.RELEASE]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter.processLogout(SAMLLogoutFilter.java:164) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar:1.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter.doFilter(SAMLLogoutFilter.java:106) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar:1.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar:1.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:102) [spring-boot-actuator-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:1.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:68) [spring-boot-actuator-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:1.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:113) [spring-boot-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:1.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59) [spring-boot-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:1.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:88) [spring-boot-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:1.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:1.2.4.RELEASE]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
```

I reviewed multiple previous responses on similar error and most of them seem to be pointing to response buffer sizes. I tried to increase the size of the buffer-cache under the domain urn:jboss:domain:undertow:1.2. But it didnt work either.

Further the problem seems to be happening only from IE and not from any other browser.

Spring Boot doesnt seem to have anything specific about response sizes..

Please help.

Comment: Did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305563/cause-of-servlets-response-already-committed

Comment: Yes.. the requested resource is part of a thymeleaf page and per my understanding it doesnt use any fixed response sizes. And then I have no code that deals with output streams.. Lastly, It is a straight resource request and thus no forwarding is present..

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661289/spring-boot-not-serving-static-content][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661289/spring-boot-not-serving-static-content

This might solve your problem

Comment: Hi Nijo, thank you for the response.. I already placed the resources in "resources" folder.. I have no special mappings in my controller.. So.. the solution wouldnt be useful in my case..

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the mime types? Or try to set them like this:

```
@Component
public class ServletCustomizer implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
        MimeMappings mappings = new MimeMappings(MimeMappings.DEFAULT);
        mappings.add("woff","application/x-font-woff");
        mappings.add("eot","application/vnd.ms-fontobject");
        mappings.add("ttf","application/x-font-ttf");
        container.setMimeMappings(mappings);
    }
}
```

Comment: the application is deployed as war. So im not sure if I can have an embedded servlet configuration. I would try putting some mime mappings on my web.xml and let you know. But, why do you think mime mapping could be the culprit?

Comment: I have had trouble with fonts and mime types because they are often not standard. But it is a bit of a guess. Could be that you also have another problem with the error page, or do you know that error configuration works?

Comment: I tried the mime mappings.. no luck.. the request is for a HTML page which contains CSS, JS and fonts.. Everything else loads perfectly without any issue.. except for the fonts.. Thats the reason I dont think it has to do with error page. I dont think it could be mime because the error seems to be on the server side (As I see the exception stack trace available) not on the browser..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exception in my application deployed as WAR on WildFly server. This app was referred to static files outside the WAR archive and, for an occasional reason, it didn't have rights to read files from the static directory. So, if you have a situation like this, check your file permissions.