# Why I can still send data after the response is commited with "response.flushBuffer()"?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, web

I use the following REST handler to transfer a file to client.

I ***deliberately*** called `response.flushBuffer()` in hope that I should be blocked from writing to the response since it is already committed. And I expect client will not receive the full file.

But the whole file still gets sent to client. And no exception about `Response Already Committed` is thrown.

Why?

My code:

```
@RestController
public class ChunkedTransferAPI {

    @Autowired
    ServletContext servletContext;

    @RequestMapping(value = "bootfile.efi", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.HEAD })
    public void doHttpBoot(HttpServletResponse response) {

        String filename = "/realbootfile.efi";
        try {
            ServletOutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();

            InputStream input = servletContext.getResourceAsStream(filename);
            BufferedInputStream bufferedInput = new BufferedInputStream(input);
            int datum = bufferedInput.read();
            while (datum != -1) {
                output.write(datum);
                datum = bufferedInput.read();
                response.flushBuffer(); // <======= HERE
            }
            //output.flush();
            output.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why dont you  use other override of Outputsteam which is : public void write(byte b[], int off, int len) so you can write data as much as you want

Comment: @SercanOzdemir Thanks for the reminding. I am just experimenting for fun.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A response is "committed" when the header has been sent, and it means that changes to response headers cannot be honored.  It doesn't stop you from writing the response body.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is a really weird design.

Comment: Actually, it is perfectly sensible.  If the API didn't have this "commit" feature, then web container's servlet stack would need to buffer the entire response body until ... in case the servlet decided to change a header field.

Comment: I think this `intentionally` introduced the possibility of inconsistency between response header and body. Maybe it's better to just shut down the whole response when calling `response.flushBuffer()`. Anyway, what's the point of flush headers first and then body?

Comment: On a second thought, I agree it's necessary. Because `headers must be sent before body`, by allowing headers to be sent well before body, we don't need to buffer the potentially huge response body until headers are sent first. So I think it's not because `servlet may decided to change a header`, but because `the precedence of header to body` makes it the only way `to send potentially huge response within limited buffer`.

Comment: I think this can be related to the `HTTP chunked transfer`. Because the HTTP header is sent first, there's no way to include the `Content-Length` in the header since the content-length is not decided yet. And we have to use the `Transfer Encoding` to indicate that.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)