# Getting error on dispatcher servlet's forward method

Tags: javascript, java, servlets

I'm getting an error in a forward method dispatcher.
This is my sample code, am getting error message. i need display name using s2.java file.

It shows html page and i put name first and last and then submit it show error.

```js
/*this is s1.java(first java file)*/
package rqdis;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class S1 extends HttpServlet{
 public void doPost(HttpServletResponse rs,HttpServletRequest rq)
 throws ServletException,IOException{
  try{
   rs.setContentType("text/html");
   PrintWriter p=rs.getWriter();
   String s1=rq.getParameter("n1");
   String s2=rq.getParameter("n2");
   p.print(s1+" "+s2);
  RequestDispatcher rd=rq.getRequestDispatcher("/fff");
  rd.forward(rq, rs);
  p.print("am from server 1.!");
  p.close();
  }catch (Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
/*this is s2.java(second java file)*/
package rqdis;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class s2 extends HttpServlet{
 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest rq,HttpServletResponse rs)
 throws ServletException,IOException{
  try{
  rs.setContentType("text/html");
  PrintWriter p=rs.getWriter();
  String s1=rq.getParameter("n1");
  String s2=rq.getParameter("n2");
  p.print(s1+" "+s2);
  p.print("am from server 2.!");
  p.close();
  }catch (Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>rqdis</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>main.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>firstservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>rqdis.S1</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>firstservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ff</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>secondservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>rqdis.s2</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>secondservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/fff</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

```html
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>disfor</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="forward metod" method="post">
    First name:
    <input type="text" name="n1"> Last name:
    <input type="text" name="n2">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not write in the servlet when you are forwarding to another servlet because the response would be committed in the other servlet.

Reference:
[Cause of Servlet's 'Response Already Committed'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305563/cause-of-servlets-response-already-committed/11305612#11305612)

Answer (score 0):

As i can see from the code, The error which you would be getting is 404 (Not found). Because your form action is `forward metod`Which has no url mapping in web.xml file. form action is used for specifying the url where request should be made. 
Try changing action of form to `action="/ff"`.