# HttpServletRequest session expires while redirect in Microsoft Edge browser

Tags: java, browser, microsoft-edge, servlet-filters

I'm trying some URL on browser, it works well on all browsers including IE 10 but when on Microsoft Edge, it fails at a point while doing HttpServletResponse sendRedirect, which expires HttpServletRequest session and the expected page does not appear.
Please help for how we can resolve this browser specific redirect-session issue.

Basic code:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // some code where values are set in session 
        session.setAttribute(myAttribute, value);
        response.sendRedirect("https://qa.sys.com/MainPage.jsf");
 }

 public class MyFilter implements Filter {
     @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)servletRequest;

        // myAttribute below comes null as request.getSession() is null 
        Boolean myAttribute = request.getSession().getAttribute(myAttribute);

 }
```

In logs, I got this Exception:-

> `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response already committed
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.objectIfCommitted(ServletResponseImpl.java:1861)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendRedirect(ServletResponseImpl.java:961)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendRedirect(ServletResponseImpl.java:956)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>           Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace`

Comment: Please post a minimal code sample replicating this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use F12 dev tools to check the Network tab in Edge and see if there's any error in console. This error usually occurs when *a java servlet is attempting to write to the output stream (response) after the response has been committed*. You could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305563/cause-of-servlets-response-already-committed) to find out why the response will get committed.

In [this blog](https://javapapers.com/servlet/how-to-avoid-illegalstateexception-in-java-servlet/), it gives the solution and you could also refer to the sample code in the post:

> It is always better to ensure that **no content** is added to the response after the forward or redirect is done to avoid IllegalStateException. It can be done by including a **‘return’** statement immediately next to the forward or redirect statement.

I also find [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123514/java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-forward-sendredirect-create-session/2125045#2125045) with detailed information about this issue and you could check it.

Comment: Thanks Yu Zhou, is it someway linked to Edge browser?  Such as return statement after sendredirect if not given then it causes problem on Edge!

Comment: It might be someway linked to Edge. I'll try to do some research and if there's something found I'll send a feedback. For now, you could try the solution in the answer.